# chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab on secure pages?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome plugin that is making use of the screen capture functionality via 'chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab', but it fails on https pages. I requested permission for secure pages:

```
 permissions:[
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
 ],
```

Is this even possible on secure pages?

This is the error I am seeing with sample URL:

```
 Error during tabs.captureVisibleTab: Cannot access contents of url "https://www.host.com/test". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `<all_urls>`

See this : http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html

T.

Comment: Still the same. Seeing this error:

     **Error during tabs.captureVisibleTab: Cannot access contents of url "https://www.host.com/test". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.**